# Pagination in web2py

Tags: python, pagination, web2py

I have a web2py database with 20 entries and I would like to show only 5 entries per page.

My controller is-

```
def viewallposts():

         if not request.vars.page:
                 redirect(URL(vars={'page':1}))
         else:   
                 page = int(request.vars.page)
         start = (page-1)*5
         end = page*5
         user = auth.user_id
         image=db().select(db.posts.ALL, orderby=~db.posts.created_on, limitby=(start,end))
         return dict(user=user, image=image)
```

The next button in my .html file is -

```
<button><a href={{=URL(vars={'page':int(request.vars.page)+1})}}>Next</a></button>
```

But, I only see the first 5 entries and when I click next, it doesn't go to the next page. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<button>` in your `View` might be the issue. Try it this way:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{=URL(vars={'page':int(request.vars.page)-1})}}">Next</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe. Your solution worked. I have one more question. I want to disable my 'Previous' button when I am on the first page of my entries. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Pranav I am glad I could help. Regarding the Previous button, can you ask that in a new question? Usually, it's better to keep the questions to the point here dealing with only the issue in the original post.